# upgrade of elixir 1.7.2 to elixir 1.11 in my project

Tags: elixir

we got a new project in my company from another company which is having very old versions.

Software    Version(Only)
Git 2.17.1
Node    10.16.3
Yarn    1.17.3
Elixir  1.7.4
PostgreSQL  11
Visual C++ Build Tools  15
Erlang/OTP 20

We are thinking to upgrade Elixir ,I am a java developer, I recently started to learn elixir but we are bound to do this upgrade now ..  Please help

Basic thing is we need to give estimations is it possible or not and how to achieve this ..!!

Right now this project is in production ..!!

Comment: [tag:elixir] is perfectly backward compatible, so it would a straightforward process requiring next to zero effort. You just upgrade Elixir and OTP versions, that’s it.

Comment: Basically we are having very old code , so by upgrading the elixir and erlang will it effect any functionality.. do u have link for documentation . Please can you provide ..!!

Answer (score 2):

According to https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/compatibility-and-deprecations.html
`A new backwards compatible minor release happens every 6 months`
In other words, Elixir is backwards compatible on all minor releases. So 1.11 is backwards compatible with 1.7.2 . You are safe to upgrade.